# How do I set the minio domain for pre-signed URLs?

Tags: kubernetes, minio

I'm using minio in Kubernetes and it works great. However, I can't seem to to change the domain and protocol for a pre-signed URL. Minio keeps giving me `http://minio.test.svc:9000/delivery/` where as I want `https://example.com/delivery`. I've tried setting `MINIO_DOMIN` in the pod but it seems to have not effect; I think I'm misusing this var anyway.

Comment: When you say "Minio keeps giving me..." what exactly are you doing? Curling an API endpoint, using some client library, using a minio client CLI? What are you actually executing, what's the full response that you're seeing?

Comment: I'm using the minio SDK for nodejs; I'm calling `presignedGetObject` which returns a signed URL much like S3.

Comment: Based on [this](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/3e5fe33f003e0d04a6726df13395290495e4f854/src/main/minio.js#L1635), [this](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/3e5fe33f003e0d04a6726df13395290495e4f854/src/main/minio.js#L1575), and [this](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/3e5fe33f003e0d04a6726df13395290495e4f854/src/main/signing.js#L282) it looks like the fourth argument to `presignedGetObject` is a `headers` object whose `host` property will be used to set the host for the presigned URL, so you could make that be "example.com"...

Comment: ... the protocol looks like it's determined by however the client is configured, so if you configure your client to point to `https://minio.test.svc:9000` instead of `http://minio.test.svc:9000` that might make the protocol be what you want.  If you try those two things, does it work?

Comment: were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you create your Minio client instance. Specifying host and port as below will make Minio resolve your domain to IP address and use IP rather than the domain. Sample JavaScript code:

```js
import { Client as MinioClient } from 'minio';

const client = new MinioClient(
  endPoint: 'yourdomain.com',
  port: 9000,
  accessKey: process.env.MINIO_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretKey: process.env.MINIO_SECRET_KEY,
  useSSL: false
);
```

If you create your minio instance like above, your domain will be resolved to it's corresponding IP address, and thus minio will work with `http://x.x.x.x:9000` as opposed to `https://yourdomain.com`

Also to note, if your client is configured as above, trying to use `useSSL: true` will throw SSL error as below

```
write EPROTO 140331355002752:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong 
version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332
```

For minio to use your domain as `https://yourdomain.com`, you need to have a web server like `nginx` to proxy your requests to your minio server. Minio has documented how you can achieve this [here](https://docs.min.io/docs/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio.html). Add SSL to your domain as documented [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) then proceed to create your minio client as below:

```js
import { Client as MinioClient } from 'minio';

const client = new MinioClient(
  endPoint: 'yourdomain.com',
  port: 443,
  accessKey: process.env.MINIO_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretKey: process.env.MINIO_SECRET_KEY,
  useSSL: true
);
```

Note the change in `port` and `useSSL` parameters.

Minio will now use `https://yourdomain.com` in all cases. Signed urls will also be `https`.

Comment: I think OP is having the same issue as me which is that within the Kube cluster only `http://minio.test.svc:9000/delivery/` is reachable but `https://example.com/delivery` is not. 

I personally tried to use the `hostNetwork` and `dnsPolicy` kube configurations which didn't seem to work.

It would be great if minio allowed you to sign host URLs not from where you connected it from

Comment: @MathisHard were you able to find a solution to that?

Comment: @properchels yeah I did. I use NGINX and kubernetes to change the HOST header coming into the cluster for minio. Note this means if you have another service in the same cluster as your minio instance, it will have to manage the public and private URLs to minio

Here is the link to the solution I had
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815229/nginx-controller-kubernetes-need-to-change-host-header-within-ingress

Answer (score 1):

I bashed my head on this problem for a couple of days and managed to resolve it with NGINX in my Kubernetes cluster.

[NGINX controller Kubernetes: need to change Host header within ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815229/nginx-controller-kubernetes-need-to-change-host-header-within-ingress)

You use the ingress annotations to change the Host header of all incoming traffic to your Minio ingress so that it will always be the same Host name.